# Conditional expected and integral

Tags: probability

Let $B_t=S_{N_t}-t$ with $N_t$ a renewal process. Let $F$ the distribution function of $X_1$.

How to show $\int_t^{\infty} \mathbf{E}(B_t|X_1=x)F dx=\mathbf{E}((X_1-t)|{X_1>t})$?

Thank you

Comment: What is the relationship between $X_1$ and $S_{N_t}$ ?

Comment: $S_{N_t}=X_1+...+X_{N_t}$